# Increasing the performance with service and multi threading in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am doing a project that needs to communicate with 20 small computer boards. I will need to keep check of their connections and they will also return some data to me. So my aim is to build a control/monitoring system for these boards.

I will be using Visual Studio 2010 and C# WPF.

My idea/ plan would be like this:

**On the main thread:**

- There will be only one control window, so a main thread will be created mainly to update the data to be displayed. Datas of each board will be display and refreshed at a time interval of 1s. The source of data will be from a database where the main thread will look for the latest data(I have not decided on which kind of database to use yet).
- There will be control buttons on the control window too. I already have a .dll library, so I will only need to call the functions inside to direct the boards to action (by starting another thread).

**There will be two services:**

- (Timer service) One will be a scheduled timer to turn the boards on/ off at a specific time. Users would be able to change the on/ off time. It would read from the database to get the on/ off time.
- (Connection service) Another one will be responsible to ask and receive information/ status from the board every 30s or less. The work would be including **connecting with the board through internet, asking for data, receiving the data and then writing the data to the database**. And also writing down the exceptions thrown if the internet connection failed.

**My questions:**

1) For the connection service, I am wondering if I should be starting 20 threads to do this, one thread per connection to a board. Because if the connections were made by only one thread, the next board connection must wait for the first to finish, which may add up to 1-2 mins for the whole process to end. So I would need around 20 - 40 mins to get all the data back. But if I separate the connection to 20 threads, will it make a big difference in the performance? As the 20 threads never dies, it keeps asking for data every 30s if possible. Besides, does that mean I will have to have 20 database, as it would clash the database if 20 threads are writing in at the same time?

2) For updating the display of data on the main thread for every 1s, should I also start a service to do this? And as the connection service is also accessing the same database, will this clash the database?

There will be more than 100 boards to control and monitor in the future, so I would like to make the program as light as possible.

Thank you very much! Comments and ideas very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you communicate via sockets? Then instead of using one thread per connection, you might use asynchronous socket methods like [BeginConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tad07yt6.aspx), [BeginReceive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.beginreceive.aspx) etc.

Comment: Yes, but still I would need to start 20 asynchronous socket methods?

Comment: Yes, but in one thread only. The point is that the asynchronous methods don't block and allow to deal with multiple connections at the same time.

Comment: Sorry, just one more question, do you think it is necessary to use a Service? Or I just use Async at MainWindows?

Comment: If you mean a separate class in your application that manages the connections: yes, that would make sense. But that does not need to run in a separate thread or even a separate program (as "service"  might suggest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Starting 20 threads would be the best bet. (Or as Ralf said, use a thread when needed, in your specific case, it would probably be 20 at some point). Most databases are thread safe, meaning you can write into them from separate threads. If you use a "real" database, this isn't any issue at all.
2. No, use a Timer on the main thread to update your UI. The UI can easily read from the DB. As long as the update action itself is not taking a lot of time, it is OK to do it on the UI thread.

Comment: For 1), yes I think I will be keeping 20 threads active as I would need to continuously ask/receive data from the boards. But if the board escalate to a amount of 100, then I will be having 100 threads? I sounds a bit scary as it seems to be very resource hungry...

Comment: 'resource hungry' - what resource will be used heavily?  With the loading you suggest, it's not going to be CPU.  Stacks?  Reduce the default stack size in the linker.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of dumb, but when you said "Reduce the default stack size in the linker." do you mean I could do inside my program or it a setting on the router?

Answer (score 0):

1) Why not use threads when needed. You can use one DBMS they are build to processing large amounts of information.

2) Not sure what you mean by start a service for the UI thread. As with 1) Database Management Systems are build to process data.